# Solving a big number of non linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have three trapezoids. The first sharing its upper side (I will call b_{i+1} in the code) with the second, the third sharing its lower side with the upper side of the second. All shared sides are parallel. 
Now the "funny" thing is that all I know about these trapezoids is: the sum of their heights, the sum of their areas and the positions of their centroids. 
I would like to know the areas of the trapezoids. I believe this is a closed problem, so I tried solving it as follows:

```
    Solve[{
        A == A1 + A2 + A3,
      yC1 == h1 (b1 + 2 b2)/(3 (b2 + b1)),
      yC2 == h2 (b2 + 2 b3)/(3 (b3 + b2)),
      yC3 == h3 (b3 + 2 bt)/(3 (bt + b3)),
       A1 == h1 (b1 + b2)/2,
       A2 == h2 (b2 + b3)/2,
       A3 == h3 (b3 + bt)/2,
        h == h1 + h2 + h3,
      xC1 == b1/2 + ((2 b2 + b1) (c1^2 - d1^2))/(6 (b1^2 - b2^2)),
      xC2 == b2/2 + ((2 b3 + b2) (c2^2 - d2^2))/(6 (b2^2 - b3^2)),
      xC3 == b3/2 + ((2 bt + b3) (c3^2 - d3^2))/(6 (b3^2 - bt^2)) ,
     c1^2 == ( ((b1 - b2)^2 + c1^2 - d1^2)/(2 b1 (b1 - b2)))^2 - h1^2,
     c2^2 == (((b2 - b3)^2 + c2^2 - d2^2)/(2 b2 (b2 - b3)))^2 - h2^2,
     c3^2 == (((b3 - bt)^2 + c3^2 - d3^2)/(2 b3 (b3 - bt)))^2 - h3^2,
     d1^2 == (((b1 - b2)^2 - c1^2 + d1^2)/(2 b1 (b1 - b2))),
     d2^2 == (((b2 - b3)^2 - c2^2 + d2^2)/(2 b2 (b2 - b3)))},
        {A1, A2, A3, b1, b2, b3, bt, h1, h2, h3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3}]
```

All letters refer to this figure, and equations come from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trapezoid.html

[image: Trapezoid as described in WolframMathWorld]

I'm quite sure this is NOT the best way to solve this problem. Yet I can't come up with a better solution. Any ideas to speed it up or alternatives?

Comment: A couple of points:  (1)  you're missing a comma preceding one of your equations (the one that starts with `c1^2`.)  (2)  `NSolve` will not work here unless you actually provide numerical values for `a`, `yC1`, `yC2`, `yC3`, and `h`.  If you want an algebraic solution, use `Solve` instead.  (3)  You have seven variables (the three heights and the four bases) and only five equations (the total area, the total height, and the centroid positions.)  So you shouldn't expect a unique solution.

Comment: "Upper" and "lower" are rather... confusing. "Longer" and "shorter" might be a bit clearer.

Comment: @Michael I did use Solve, actually. Including other equations relating these variables [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trapezoid.html) you will find that it is possible to close the system.

Comment: @J.M. I added a picture to make it clear, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Doesn't clarify it for me at all. If I turn your figure upside down, it's still a trapezoid, but now the "upper" side is longer than the "lower" side.

Comment: can I suggest you draw a complete figure showing three trapezoids.  What makes you believe there should be a closed form solution?  In any case try reduce.

Comment: Also, your equations aren't dimensionally consistent.  If the `b`'s, `c`'s, `d`'s, and `h`'s are all lengths/distances, then your last two equations are equating an area with a dimensionless quantity (a ratio of areas), and the three before that involve subtracting an area from a dimensionless quantity.

Comment: You might be right. I was referring to the "x1" and "x2" expressions (link), indeed they might need to be moltiplied by b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the way you're trying to solve it right now is that your variables aren't all independent of each other.  Specifically, for a given trapezoid, you cannot vary $h$, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ independently of each other.  Once you have specified the first four, then $d$ cannot be freely varied (it's constrained to be one of two possible values.)  So some of your equations you have must be degenerate with each other (assuming they're correct.)

I think it's more productive to look at this problem in terms of a slightly different set of parameters:

- The heights of the trapezoids (three parameters; call them $h_1$ through $h_3$ from bottom to top)
- The lengths of the bases (four parameters; call them $b_0$ through $b_3$ from bottom to top)
- The horizontal "offset" of the upper left corner of each trapezoid relative to the bottom left corner (three parameters;  call them $x_1$ through $x_3$.)

Here's some Mathematica code to illustrate this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, EdgeForm[Black], 
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {b0, 0}, {b1 + x1, h1}, {x1, h1}}], 
   Polygon[{{x1, h1}, {b1 + x1, h1}, {b2 + x1 + x2, h1 + h2}, {x1 + x2, h1 + h2}}], 
   Polygon[{{x1 + x2, h1 + h2}, {b2 + x1 + x2, h1 + h2}, {b3 + x3 + x1 + x2, h1 + h2 + h3}, {x3 + x1 + x2, h1 + h2 + h3}}]}], 
   {h1, 0, 1}, {b0, 0, 1}, {b1, 0, 1}, {x1, 0, 1}, {h2, 0, 1}, {b2, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {h3, 0, 1}, {b3, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

If you play around with this code, it should become obvious fairly quickly that the areas of the trapezoids, their total height, and the vertical positions of their centroids are entirely independent of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$.  Moreover, the horizontal positions of the centroids can be changed arbitrarily by changing $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, *without changing any of the areas or the vertical centroid positions.* Thus, there are seven variables (the $h$'s and the $b$'s) that you're trying to constrain with five numbers (total area, total height, and each trapezoid's vertical centroid coordinate);  and trying to use the horizontal position of the centroids to further constrain things won't work, since you can position your centroids horizontally any way you please by varying the $x$'s.   I suspect, therefore, that the system is generically not uniquely determined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and your beautiful dynamic graph. I have the feeling you are right. You certainly made your point proving that changing x1,x2 and x3 you only have canonical transformations.